# Twilio - Initiate outbound conference, but add recipient to conference before caller

Tags: ruby, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio to initiate a call from a client to an outbound number. What I want to occur is the following:

Person A dials Person B using the client. When Person B picks up, they are directed into a conference. Once Person B is in the conference, I want to direct Person A into the same conference.

This is what I have so far using Twiml and the twilio-ruby helper library:

```
def dial 
  default_number = "+1234567890"
  caller_id = params[:OutgoingNumber].nil? ? default_number : params[:OutgoingNumber]
  outbound_number = params[:PhoneNumber].gsub(/\D/, '')
  conference_name = "call_#{outbound_number}"

  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial :callerId => caller_id do |d|
      d.Number outbound_number, :url => "/twilio-connect?name=#{conference_name}&recipient=true"
    end
  end

  render_twiml response
end

def outgoing_connect #"/twilio-connect"
  conference_name = params["name"]
  record = params["record"]
  init_call_id = params[:ParentCallSid]

  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Dial do |d|
      if recipient == "false"
        d.Conference conference_name, :record => "record-from-start"
      else 
        d.Conference conference_name
      end
    end
  end

  if recipient == "true"
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new Rails.application.config.secrets["twilio_sid"], Rails.application.config.secrets["twilio_token"]
    call = client.account.calls.get(init_call_id)
    call.update(:url => "https://www.example.com/twilio-connect?name=#{conference_name}&record=true", :method => "POST")
  end

  render_twiml response
end
```

I'm haven't had any success updating/redirecting Person A into the conference. Once Person B is in the conference, Persona A's side of the conversation just stops ringing.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Do you mean you are using Twilio Client to initiate the call? Could you expand on the full flow as it is right now, I'm not sure in what order things are happening here.

Comment: Yes I use Twilio Client to initiate the call. I also have a TwiML app set up that initiates outbound calls by posting to that dial method. Initiating the outbound calls works fine. The number url used is for the outgoing_connect method below which dials the recipient into the conference. I use params to determine, at this time, whether the url is being visited by the caller or the recipient, though separating into separate methods is also a viable option.